# dexDebugTest fails with DexException "Cannot merge new index" for test

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing, dex, android-espresso

I'm building an android project with gradle that leverages Google Espresso (much thanks to Jake Wharton's double espresso). With my build.gradle configuration I can successfully build debug and release versions using proguard to optimize my method counts (to get below the 65k limit), but when I run connectedAndroidTest my build fails with:

```
...
:src:MyApp:proguardDebug UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyApp:proguardDebugTest UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyApp:dexDebugTest UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:prepareDebugTestDependencies
:src:MyAppLibrary:compileDebugTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:checkDebugManifest
:src:MyAppLibrary:prepareDebugDependencies
:src:MyAppLibrary:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:bundleDebug
:src:MyAppLibrary:assembleDebug
:src:MyAppLibrary:processDebugTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:compileDebugTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:generateDebugTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:generateDebugTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:mergeDebugTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:generateDebugTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:generateDebugTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:mergeDebugTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:processDebugTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:generateDebugTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:compileDebugTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:preDexDebugTest UP-TO-DATE
:src:MyAppLibrary:dexDebugTest

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Cannot merge new index 65623 into a non-jumbo instruction!
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.jumboCheck(InstructionTransformer.java:108)
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.access$800(InstructionTransformer.java:25)
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer$StringVisitor.visit(InstructionTransformer.java:71)
    at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.callVisit(CodeReader.java:114)
    at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.visitAll(CodeReader.java:89)
    at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.transform(InstructionTransformer.java:48)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformCode(DexMerger.java:840)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformMethods(DexMerger.java:811)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassData(DexMerger.java:784)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassDef(DexMerger.java:680)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:540)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

:src:MyAppLibrary:dexDebugTest FAILED
```

My app is called MyApp and it has a dependency project called MyAppLibrary. Before switching to espresso I didn't hit the 65k limit when running connectedAndroidTest. I used robotium before and I've since removed those dependencies. Also, I don't hit the limit when I just build a debug or release build. Is there a way to optimize my test build like I am optimizing my debug build?

The odd thing to me is that I only have tests in MyApp, I don't have any test classes in MyAppLibrary. In fact, when I run connectedAndroidTest, I can actually see my tests running on my device and passing before it gets to MyAppLibrary:dexDebugTest. So any idea why it would fail there after running my tests?

Alternatively, would it be possible to somehow bypass calling the connectedAndroidTest dependency chain for MyAppLibrary?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In the build.gradle You need to specify:

```
android {
   dexOptions {
      jumboMode true
   }
}
```